# How many processes may be in one android app? What is max count?

Tags: android

How many processes may be in one android app?

We can added more than one process using manifest in android. What is max count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to android docs from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals):

> By default, every app runs in its own Linux process. The Android system starts the process when any of the app's components need to be executed, and then shuts down the process when it's no longer needed or when the system must recover memory for other apps.

and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads):

> By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and most applications should not change this. However, if you find that you need to control which process a certain component belongs to, you can do so in the manifest file.
>
> The manifest entry for each type of component element `<activity>`, `<service>`, `<receiver>`, and `<provider>` supports an `android:process` attribute that can specify a process in which that component should run. You can set this attribute so that each component runs in its own process or so that some components share a process while others do not. You can also set android:process so that components of different applications run in the same process—provided that the applications share the same Linux user ID and are signed with the same certificates.
>
> The `<application>` element also supports an `android:process` attribute, to set a default value that applies to all components.

we can find that each android application has one process by default. In addition by running each component in a separate process, the processes count would be equal to `NUMBER_OF_COMPONENTS + 1`  at max. There is no documentation about maximum possible count of processes for each android application.